# How long should I observe a period of no behavior in order to conclude a problem is repaired?

Tags: bayesian, survival

A recurring objectionable event is observed over a period of time.  It could be a signal failure in TV reception, for example.  We can assume that it is a Poisson process with a time varying wait between events.  There is no significant clustering of events in time.  For whatever reason, somebody declares the problem solved.

How long would you wait before you feel confident the problem has been actually fixed?  That is what method do you use to define a "clean period". Obviously the longer the problem has persisted, the longer you'll need before you believe that the new process is now 0.  The item may break again, but that will assumed to be a different process. This assumes that the expected lifetime is sufficiently long that we wouldn't see the same problem again for a significant period of time.

How would the approach differ if we are looking at behavior change in a human being?  For example, a student is missing handing in homework over a K day period. Q percent of days have a missed assignment. An intervention occurs, and M days then pass with no incident.  How would you set M to feel confident that some change has occurred?  I don't think the traditional 95% confidence tests are what is needed here.

I've tried an approach based on Poisson regression, but I think it gives very long wait times compared to practical heuristics.

**My Question**

What are some good initial lines of research to understand existing work on the problem? I also tagged this as Bayesian b/c of my belief that  Bayesian methods are useful in credibility problems.

**Note**

This is closely related to "How long should I wait before I assume a software problem is fixed" but the assumptions are different.  In a software problem, the appearance of an error, or class of errors, may be a function of how it is used and tested. In this problem, though, no user intervention is needed to observe the signal if it is still present, except to turn the device on or off.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "fixed". If you want to show that the probability is $0$, you need to wait forever. OTOH, you can show that the rate is $>\theta$, then you need to do a version of a power analysis for a non-superiority test.

Comment: Good point, about waiting forever, but I need to formalize that.  If I require $0<\theta_1<<\theta_0$, how should I formalize the "<<" - much less than.

Comment: I need to define fixed in a way that aligns with intuition.  In the homework example, 60 straight good days, followed by missing two straight assignments might not cause us to reject the null hypothesis, but most parents would intervene at this point.  I would argue that implicitly we are taking into account cost of letting the problem go on vs cost of fixing.

Comment: There is no "$\ll$". Just specify the limit you want to be lower than & the rate you believe is actually the case.

Comment: Actually, there is a <<, at least informally.   When you write *the limit you want to be lower than*, this is actually what I'm interested in determining.  The rest is mechanical.  

The point I'm trying to make is that we often make good decisions long before we have adequate statistical power.  What methods are beyond these heuristics?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the 'homework example' you were referring to. The point is, you identify the limit you want to be lower than, & that's "<". There is no precise mathematical meaning of "<<". If you want to be much lower than 10, & that means being lower than 2, then you use "<2" as the upper limit of a 95% CI.

Comment: You needn't worry about the lower limit. In essence, you are after a one-sided 95% CI.